# How to define a custom pgf color palette from a given base color?

Tags: pgfplots, color

I have a stacked plot with seven plots, and I'm trying to obtain a set of colors that suit with the primary color of the rest of the document.

The code is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{95,145,166}

\begin{document}

\tikz \path node[rectangle, fill=myblue,inner sep=1cm] {};

\begin{tikzpicture}

  \begin{axis}[
    xbar stacked,
    cycle list/Blues-7, cycle list name=Blues-7,
    every axis plot/.style={fill}
  ]

    \addplot table {
      first second
      1     5
      2     6
      3     7
      4     8
    };

    \addplot table {
      first second
      1     5
      2     6
      3     7
      4     8
    };

    \addplot table {
      first second
      1     5
      2     6
      3     7
      4     8
    };

    \addplot table {
      first second
      1     5
      2     6
      3     7
      4     8
    };

    \addplot table {
      prova colonna
      1     5
      2     6
      3     7
      4     8
    };

    \addplot table {
      prova colonna
      1     5
      2     6
      3     7
      4     8
    };

    \addplot table {
      prova colonna
      1     5
      2     6
      3     7
      4     8
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And its output is:

[image: output]

So the Blue-7 cycle list from `color brewer` is the closest that I could find, but the tonality is different and thus wrong.

Is there a way to obtain a 7-color cycle list similar to the `XX-7` ones from `colorbrewer` but based on my basic blue color shown above? Looking at it, the base color may probably be the darkest of the series.

I'm citing specifically `color brewer` because the luminosity difference between different color in the original `Blue-7` palette sounds quite right. Anyway, I don't need the colors to be necessarily automatically computed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always define your own things.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{95,145,166}

\begin{document}

\tikz \path node[rectangle, fill=myblue,inner sep=1cm] {};
\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{my blues}{%
myblue,myblue!90,myblue!80,myblue!70,myblue!60,myblue!50,myblue!40,myblue!30,myblue!20}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \begin{axis}[
    xbar stacked,
    cycle list name=my blues,
    every axis plot/.style={fill},
  ]

    \addplot table {
      first second
      1     5
      2     6
      3     7
      4     8
    };

    \addplot table {
      first second
      1     5
      2     6
      3     7
      4     8
    };

    \addplot table {
      first second
      1     5
      2     6
      3     7
      4     8
    };

    \addplot table {
      first second
      1     5
      2     6
      3     7
      4     8
    };

    \addplot table {
      prova colonna
      1     5
      2     6
      3     7
      4     8
    };

    \addplot table {
      prova colonna
      1     5
      2     6
      3     7
      4     8
    };

    \addplot table {
      prova colonna
      1     5
      2     6
      3     7
      4     8
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, you could also define the list in a loop (but here copy & paste was even faster ;-).

Comment: Thanks, but 1) why calling the Blues-7 key anyway? And 2) can I give a name to the list?

Comment: @gigabytes as for 1) good catch! and as for 2) sure, see my update.